# NFT of character gear in a game

Tags: solidity, erc-721

If I wanted to implement a character gear based on NFT and save the meta data (sword, cloak, etc) in a single contract, is it possible for players to later to change and trade their gear?

Answer (score 0):

sure it is.  Just store the character specs on ipfs and then refer to those by some sort of (ID) within your game.  When your players "buy" their "swords" and "cloaks" you make the buy process a mint function to that players address so that they are the owner of the resource and as such they would be able to swap or sell it.  I made a test game to prove the concept which you can read about here -> https://cryptoinca.pro/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=7&sid=a8c5e95ef4c218ffa59929525ca835b3

the contract used for the game is here -> https://github.com/macguyversmusic/Crypto-Car-Battle/blob/master/SpaceRace/contracts/CarBattle.sol

this should be all you need to be able to mint an NFT and make it the property of the player.